# Drag and drop fragments on activity

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, fragment

I have a lot of fragments in linear layout like recyclerview.I mean I have fragment in activity and fragment has linear layout(vertical) layout.And linear layout has fragments.I want to change places of fragments like drag and drop in recyclerview.How do achieve this?Can you help me?

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView_container"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/window_small_padding"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linear_layout_widget_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>


  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show your activity xml

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in question updated.